# Install4j: Error Message in unattended mode

Tags: java, install4j

I have an installer which supports unattended mode of installation. When there is an error like (no sufficient space, no access,..), the error messages are shown properly in GUI mode. however, its not showing any error message during unattended mode.

Is there a option to show the error messages during the unattended mode as well?

Note: I have windows and Linux installers

Thanks a lot for the help

Cheers,

Prabhu Senthamarai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would have to look at the log file for analyzing errors. The log file is written to `[installation directory]/.install4j/installation.log.`

If the installer exits with a fatal error before the "Install files" action has run, you can find the log file in the %TEMP% directory (Mac OS X: $TMPDIR, Linux/Unix: $TMP). The name of the log file starts with "i4jlog..." in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Just one more confirmation. Error messages will not be shown even when the progress dialog is shown in unattended mode.  Correct? e.g, I use the following option to show the progress dialog "installer.exe -q -splash "Updating installation ..."

Comment: That's correct. The progress dialog can just show progress information and no modal error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation and help. Thanks again

Comment: Is the document for the list of error codes returned by the installers? In the following document, I see only 0,1,83 error codes explained. [link](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html) Can you please provide the list of error codes? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: When do you get 83? It should only be 0 and 1.

Comment: I just saw that information in the help document [Error Handling](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html) in 'Return values' section

Comment: Good find. I actually wrote that and completely forgot about it!

Comment: Dear Ingo Kegel, Its only these three error codes or is there any list of error codes? Can you please provide more information on this. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: That's the list in the documentation. There are no other error codes.